# Adjusting UICollectionView size to fit UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I'm trying to adjust the cell heights to fit the UIImages, the problem is it does not seem like the UIImage is filling the collectionView cell. As you can see on this

Image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/98d3zd.jpg

It seems like the cell adjusted, but the image is not filled correctly to fill the cell?

**cellheights**
First I've created a loop which calculate the new height if the cellWidth is 140, which is the case allways.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [homesDic count]; i++) {

    UIImage *originalImage = [[homesDic objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"];

    CGFloat originalHeight = originalImage.size.height;
    CGFloat originalWidth = originalImage.size.width;
    CGFloat wantedWidth = 140;
    float wantedHeight = (originalHeight*wantedWidth)/originalWidth;
    [_cellHeights addObject:@(wantedHeight)];
}
```

Then I insert a imageView in to the collectionView cell and set the frame and set cell height equal to the imageheight from the cellHeights array.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FRGWaterfallCollectionViewCell *waterfallCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:WaterfallCellIdentifier indexPath];
    waterfallCell.lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Item %d", indexPath.item];

    waterfallCell.bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.184 green:0.192 blue:0.196 alpha:0.7];
    waterfallCell.homeImage.image = [[homesDic objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] objectForKey:@"image"];

    waterfallCell.homeImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.cellHeights[indexPath.item] floatValue], waterfallCell.frame.size.width);
    return waterfallCell;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(FRGWaterfallCollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
 heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return [[self.cellHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] floatValue];
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm using the same thing and trying to adjust my cell height to the height of a UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

To set up cell size you should use collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath method, try this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get reference to your image base on indexPath here (I assume you have one section and indexPath.row refer to right image) adjust if needed:
    UIImage *originalImage = [[homesDic objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];

    CGSize imgSize = originalImage.size;
    //Adjust if needed
    imgSize.height += 20; 
    imgSize.width += 20;

    return imgSize;
}
```

if you need spacing between the cells, headers, and footers, use this method:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 10, 20, 10); 
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for